# Enable multidate on bootstrap rails datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, haml

I'm new to Rails and JQuery development and I'm trying to enable the multidate feature on the bootstrap datepicker object. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the multidate: true option in to the datepicker. Here is a snippet of my haml:

```
.col-md-6
   .form-group
     = f.label :mydates, 'Dates'
     .input-group
       %span.input-group-addon
         = fa_icon 'calendar'
     = f.text_field :mydates, value: '', class: 'form-control datepicker'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Just needed to add a .js file with the following:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker(
      {
        multidate: true
      }
 )
```